# How do I start emacs?

Tags: emacs

I am trying Linux again after many years, and I have installed Ubuntu 12.10.  I have downloaded the full GNU Emacs24 package, but I cannot get it to launch a text editor.

Can someone tell me what I have to do to get it to launch?

I keep getting:

```
emacs ~/test.txt
The program 'emacs' can be found in the following packages:
 * emacs23
 * emacs23-nox
 * emacs24
 * emacs24-nox
 * e3
 * emacs23-lucid
 * emacs24-lucid
 * jove
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

run:

```
sudo apt-get install emacs24
```

enter your password (as you type it, there's no feedback, I'm sure you remember ;)), press enter.

when its done

```
emacs your_filename.ext
```

should work just fine

Comment: Yes, this works. Apparently emacs is not installed yet if you get this error. OP should select your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Type emacs in the terminal then press <kbd>tab</kbd> it will fill in emacs24...

Or follow the tip in your errormessage...

Answer (score 0):

Like the message says, emacs can be found in one of those packages. Pick one.

emacs24 (which means version 24) is probably what you want.